# Planet Labs API: Landsat HTTP request returns duplicated scenes

Tags: planet

Whenever i do an HTTP request for Landsat data with the following filter:

```
filter = {
'intersects': geojson.dumps(
              geojson.Polygon([[[-31.0,30.0],[-31.3,42.1],
                          [-6.1,42.1],[-6.1,30.0],[-31.3,30.0]]])),
'acquired.gte': datetime(2016, 01, 8, 10, 00, 00).isoformat(),
'acquired.lte': datetime(2016, 01, 8, 11, 00, 00).isoformat(),
'cloud_cover.estimated.gte': 0,
'cloud_cover.estimated.lte': 100
}
```

I get a response with three times the same scene. I.e. 'count' == 3, but all the three scenes are the same.

Is this a known issue?

Comment: is this API currently in beta testing, as suggested by https://www.planet.com/explorers? If so the best option is probably to use whatever beta forums that Planet Labs have set up

Comment: In their webpage they suggest to use the GIS StackExchange to post technical questions: https://support.planet.com/hc/en-us/articles/212133627-I-m-an-Explorer-and-I-need-technical-help-

Comment: fair enough. It sounds like an awesome idea, product and approach, and I love that they're already engaging with Stack Exchange. I might have to sign up too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with some Landsat images being indexed multiple times but these duplicates have been removed.

Disclaimer: I work for Planet Labs.

Comment: Please mark the answer as resolving the question!